# Empty space after setVisibility GONE a row in bindView

Tags: android

I use the following code, I want to delete a row in bindView into custom Cursor Adapter.
But after delete a row, an empty space remains.

My Code into bindView:

```
if(deleteListId.contains(goftarId)) {
    for(int i = 0; i< ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); i++  ) {
        ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i< ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); i++  ) {
        ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Result after delete a row:
[image]

How can fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add more of code in your question and maybe the layout too.Although, as i can imagine..you use listView that extends AbsListView. Ensure that you haven't the property `android:stackFromBottom="true"` inside your layout. A second thing i should check, is that if you use loader, add `mListView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);`

Othewise, you should upload more code. :)